# PosgreSQL Filtering data from timestamp in where clause

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, where-clause

I am trying to filter out some historical data from my table in intervals (e.g. per month) and have searched around but, couldn't find what i was looking for.

in the table, there is a timestamp (tstamp) column (Integer Data Type) which stores in UNIX time format

```
SELECT tstamp, alrnumber, callduration 
FROM execute_data
WHERE alrnumber = '2011'
limit 10;`
```

returns

```
"tstamp";"alrnumber";"callduration"
1526435754;2011;415
1526531498;2011;287
1526615626;2011;13
1526620016;2011;270
1526856112;2011;0
1526856201;2011;0
1526860622;2011;0
1526868702;2011;248
1526949810;2011;0
1527028483;2011;4
```

I can use this to make the date in a readable format

```
SELECT alrnumber,entryname,callduration, to_char(to_timestamp(tstamp),'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

So the tstamp field comes out like this

`"2018-06-06 21:30:39"`

What I can't work out is, how to filter the date on an interval in a where clause so I can return smaller sets of data for periods of time.

My first post here, forgive if i haven't followed some preferences for posting.

Comment: What exactly do you want to "filter"? Are you looking for `where to_timestamp(tstamp) > current_timestamp - interval '5 days'` or something similar?

Comment: Yes, i want to extract records for particluar months from the last 3 years of data so need to be able define those ranges where needed

Comment: Can't you do something along the lines of `WHERE to_timestamp(tstamp) > '2019-01-01' AND to_timestamp(tstamp) < '2019-04-01'`? Or do I misunderstand what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @ahorse_with_no_name and @Rhode Fischer, i just had to add in the correct syntax for my where clause, thanks for your replies

`SELECT tstamp, alrnumber, callduration 
FROM execute_data
**WHERE to_timestamp(tstamp) > '2019-01-01' AND to_timestamp(tstamp) < '2019-04-01**
AND alrnumber = '2011'
limit 10;`